# Replacing MIME type of a file

Tags: javascript, ios, html, mime-types, mime

I have a device that I want to play a video file from with an HTML5 video player, **The device code it untouchable**.
The developers of the device has made a mistake and are sending the wrong MIME type for a video, They send

> video/mpeg

Instead of the standart

> video/mp4

This mistake prevents the browser (iOS in this case) to stream the video, It will just painfully load the video until almost half done,

Any idea how to change the MIME type with JS alone or force the player to use a certain predefined MIME type and not creating a local proxy?

Thanks